# Windows EFS encryption

Tags: windows-7, encryption, efs

I'm using Bitlocker for a full disk encryption solution. However, I'd like to avoid having to shut down my computer to leave it in a secure state. If I enable EFS encryption on the folders  which I need encrypted and log off, are the folders encrypted? If I merely switch users and don't log off, are the files still encrypted?

Thanks a ton,
Steve

Answer (score 5):

If you look at microsoft documentation, they recommend bitlocker AND EFS to fully protect the computer.

This is because bitlocker (or any full-disk encryption) is meant to protect anyone that does not have access to your computer and EFS is meant to protect one user's files from other users, where all users have some form of access to your computer.
This is to say they are different solutions.

From what I understand, you use bitlocker + EFS and want to secure your data without poweroff.

Well, for the true paranoic user, you can't. It's still possible to use a windows vulnerability to access everything, or an autorun script. Once windows is started, bitlocker files are accessible and as long as the user is logged on (even with switch users), EFS files are accessible.

If you are not that paranoic and just want to protect your files against other authorized users of that computer or agains unauthorized users, then switch users is enough and your files are protected.